# How to read non-english texts in java? They are represented in wrong encoding

Tags: java, encoding, internationalization, httpclient

I use apache HttpClient. And when I'm trying to "read site", all non-english content is represented wrongly.

Actually, it's represented in windows-1252 but it should be in UTF-8. How can I fix this?

I tried to use `InputStreamReader (inputStream, Charset.forName ("UTF-8"))`, but it didn't help (wrong symbols transformed into ????????).

Answer (score 2):

If the file is in Windows-1252, then telling it to use UTF-8 isn't going to work. Give it Windows-1252 as the charset name, and then you can read the correct data. Knowing what format data *should* be in isn't nearly as useful as knowing what format it's *actually* in :)

It's up to you whether you then rewrite it in UTF-8...

Answer (score 0):

Finding the correct character encoding can be a bit of a nightmare. Depending on what the content of your site is, the following might be useful. One thing I've done in the past is rely on a class that will use multiple methods for determining the correct character encoding:

The [XmlReader](https://rome.dev.java.net/apidocs/1_0/com/sun/syndication/io/XmlReader.html) from the rome project will use the UTF byte order mark and/or XML declarations to determine the correct encoding.

So you could use the following construct:

```
new BufferedReader(new XmlReader(inputStream))
```

to get to the content.

Answer (score 0):

If the page has encoding in "Content-Type" header, HttpClient will honor it. If not, it will assume Latin-1, not Windows-1252. Are you sure you are getting Windows-1252? You can check encoding like this,

```
String encoding = method.getResponseCharSet();
```

If you know the response indeed uses UTF-8 but the header didn't specify it, you can force it to read UTF-8 like this,

```
byte[] body = method.getResponseBody();
String response = new String(body, "UTF-8");
```